# Get the path from NSURL on pasteboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I can currently get a NSURL from the pasteboard, but it returns the following

> file://localhost/Users/Mac/Desktop/SomePath/

How can I get this to return

> /Users/Mac/Desktop/SomePath/

Comment: Googling this takes less time than posting it here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [someURL path];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString* filePath = [nsUrlObject path];
```

should do it.